# How to select From Table with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I have a table `machine`:

```
 - id: int
 - name: varchar (100)
 - mark: varchar (100)
 - price: double
```

with the data:

```
1, keyboard, mark1, 10
2, mouse, mark2, 15
3, keyboard, mark3, 50
4, computer, mark4, 120
5, mouse, mark5, 90
```

I would like to display list of machines with a group by name with the last entry price:

```
1(first), keyboard(first), mark1(first), 50(last)
2(first), mouse(first), mark2(first), 90(last)
4, computer, mark4, 120
```

- Price 50 comes from the line :  3, keyboard, mark3, 50
- Price 90 comes from the line :  5, mouse, mark5, 90

I tried with this query :

```
SELECT * FROM machine GROUP BY name
```

But I don't have any idea to appears me my result.

Comment: Last? Does that mean highest id value?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, MAX(price) FROM machine GROUP BY name
```

If you also want to select mark, you need to group or aggregate the column

Answer (score 0):

Have a sub-query m2 that returns each machine's highest id (i.e the row with the latest price). Join m1 with m2 to get whole rows:

```
select m1.*
from machine m1
join (select name, max(id) as id from machine group by name) m2
  on m1.name = m2.name
  and m1.id = m2.id
```

Can be simplified as:

```
select m1.*
from machine m1
join (select max(id) as id from machine group by name) m2
  on m1.id = m2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this
SELECT * FROM machine GROUP BY name,id
```

Answer (score 0):

That should do the trick

```
select * from 
    mytable 
join 
     (select max(id) as maxid 
     from mytable 
     Group by name) on mytablemax on mytablemax.maxid=mytable.id
```